# Format a string (XML like) to JSON

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'm getting a string result from a webservice that looks like:

```
 <NewDataSet>\r\n  <Resultado>\r\n    <CODCFO>00002</CODCFO>\r\n    <NOMEFANTASIA>ETHOS CONSULTORES</NOMEFANTASIA>\r\n    <CGCCFO>99.999.999/0001-99</CGCCFO>\r\n  </Resultado>\r\n  <Resultado>\r\n    <CODCFO>00003</CODCFO>\r\n    <NOMEFANTASIA>DANIEL LIMA RODRIGUES DE CARVALHO</NOMEFANTASIA>\r\n    <CGCCFO>999.999.999-99</CGCCFO>\r\n  </Resultado>\r\n  <Resultado>\r\n    <CODCFO>00004</CODCFO>\r\n    <NOMEFANTASIA>DOUGLAS DE MOURA GUIMARAES</NOMEFANTASIA>\r\n    <CGCCFO>999.999.999-00</CGCCFO>\r\n  </Resultado>\r\n
```

Original and in clean code, it's look like:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Resultado>
        <CODCFO>00002</CODCFO>
        <NOMEFANTASIA>ETHOS CONSULTORES</NOMEFANTASIA>
        <CGCCFO>99.999.999/0001-99</CGCCFO>
    </Resultado>
    <Resultado>
        <CODCFO>00003</CODCFO>
        <NOMEFANTASIA>DANIEL LIMA RODRIGUES DE CARVALHO</NOMEFANTASIA>
        <CGCCFO>999.999.999-99</CGCCFO>
    </Resultado>
    <Resultado>
        <CODCFO>00004</CODCFO>
        <NOMEFANTASIA>DOUGLAS DE MOURA GUIMARAES</NOMEFANTASIA>
        <CGCCFO>999.999.999-00</CGCCFO>
    </Resultado>
</NewDataSet>
```

I need to JSON this. 
Yes, I could do a function and do it manually, but the question is if anyone have any tips about how to do this automatically, because, in this example I just have this 3 fields, in other case I'll have another number of fields and other field names. So, any help?

Comment: you could try this package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xml

Comment: Ok, it worked in parts, I have a return with & in the middle that is crashing the parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or the xml2json package which was made for this purpose

Comment: xml2json does not parse this structure.